# What's such instruction for?

Tags: assembly

```
#define ngx_memory_barrier()   __asm__ volatile ("" ::: "memory")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Memory Barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)

Comment: Note that this emits no code, so it is not a general-purpose memory barrier.  It does prevent GCC from re-ordering memory accesses across the statement, but it does not prevent the CPU from doing so.  Hence it functions as a barrier only on CPUs that do not themselves re-order memory accesses.

Comment: @John R. Strohm,I don't understand that article ,though:(

Comment: @Nemo ,when is it needed at all?

Comment: It is used when you have to know something about the order of memory accesses in order to prove correctness.  Only applies to concurrent programming (e.g., threads).  You know how to use a mutex?  Well, memory barriers are the sort of tool you need to _implement_ a mutex.

Comment: @Nemo ,put it easily,memory barrier is mainly to disable cpu cache and read from memory again,right?

Comment: No, not really...  A modern compiler can re-order instructions for speed.  So can a modern CPU.  For example, `x=5; ++x; y=12;` could be slow because x is being accessed twice in a row, which can stall the pipeline.  A modern compiler or CPU might move the `y=12` to happen in between the updates of `x`.  Now imagine x and y are memory locations and you start to get the idea...  Memory barriers disable this particular optimization.

Comment: [memory-barriers.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) in the Linux kernel documentation also provides a detailed description of different types of barriers and their usage. In addition, you may also find useful [this article](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/10/06/memory-ordering-semantics/) by Thiago Macieira at Qt Labs.

Comment: Compilers that reorder instructions are doing their job.  Occasionally, they have to be told NOT to do so, because of concurrency correctness issues.  This instruction tells the compiler not to reorder instructions that reference memory from one side of that line to the other.  Processors that reorder instructions on the fly, on the other hand, are just plain EVIL.  They CANNOT be trusted to execute correct code correctly.  (Peterson's variation of Dekker's Algorithm is *STILL* occasionally needed, and those instructions must execute EXACTLY in the right sequence.)